# Avoid stripping leading zeros while copying data to csv : Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, .net-core, angular8

I am trying to download data in `.csv`. In some of the values in the JSON object has multiple values like "000".
When this is being downloaded in CSV(excel) then "000" has been trimmed to "0". 
I am using following JS :
  `import { saveAs } from 'file-saver'`

```
 BindTable(dt, ID) {
    this.dtRequests = [];     
    this.dtRequests = JSON.parse(json);
    const replacer = (key, value) => value === null ? '' : value ;
    let DownldData: any;
    let fileName = ID+ '_RInfo.csv';
    DownldData = this.dtRequests;
    const header = Object.keys(DownldData[0]);
    let csv = DownldData.map(row => header.map(fieldName => JSON.stringify(row[fieldName], 
    replacer)).join(','));
    csv.unshift(header.join(','));
    let csvArray = csv.join('\r\n');
    var blob = new Blob([csvArray], { type: 'text/csv' });
    saveAs(blob, fileName);
  }
```

I have tried the following things and it didn't work.

```
const replacer = (key, value) => value === null ? '' : '\t' + String(value) ; // Output "\t000"
const replacer = (key, value) => value === null ? '' : '' + String(value) ; // Output "0"
const replacer = (key, value) => value === null ? '' : "''" + String(value) + "''"; // Output "000"
```

Is there any better way to handle in angular 8?

Answer (score 1):

var test = "000456";
var insertValueAs = "\t" + test;

working perfectly in angular11- code tested

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer seems incredibly hacky, however, it resolves the issue in Angular 13.1.